# What is the main difference between 'continental fuel injection system' and 'Bendix RSA fuel injection system'?

Tags: engine

While I'm studying Aircraft Engine system, I learned that there are two dominant kinds of fuel injection system : 'continental fuel injection system' and 'Bendix RSA fuel injection system'

I tried to find the main difference between those systems, and all I found out was that the former one injects fuel before the each cylinders, in the manifold(with nozzles connected to manifold valve assembly), and the latter one injects fuel directly into the each cylinders(and the nozzles are connected to a fuel divider). But I'm not sure this is true or not, since there are no part that explains the exact difference between them.

Could anyone let me know about this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First of all, both of these systems are continuous flow fuel injection systems, therefore they do not inject fuel directly into the cylinders. Since the fuel is flowing continuously from the injector nozzles, the spray is directed into the induction system just before the intake valve. That way, the fuel will only enter the cylinder when the intake air charge is drawn into the cylinder as the intake valve opens. Both systems have a throttle body to house the throttle valve, and a fuel servo/regulator to meter the correct amount of fuel and control the air to fuel mixture. The primary difference is how the fuel is metered. The RSA system (originally manufactured by Bendix Corp.) is found on Lycoming engines and is the next evolution after the pressure injection carburetor. The RSA system uses a combination of differential air pressure and differential fuel pressure to regulate and meter the fuel flow. The two sources of air are the low pressure air in the throat of the venturi and the high pressure air from the "ram air" entering the throttle body. At wide open throttle, these two forces have the greatest differential pressure, so they move a diaphragm and a valve in the fuel regulator to increase the fuel flow and pressure. The Teledyne Continental Motors fuel injection system does not use air metering force. This system relies only on differential fuel pressure.